# Trying to implement a pointer that can go both clockwise and counter clockwise in a circular array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have failed a coding interview because of this question. Can someone please help me crack this down?

[image]

This is my code (Python):

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase # String 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
current_position = 0 # Letter 'A', the first item in our alphabet list
distances = []

word = 'Croves'.lower()

for letter in word:
    destination = alphabet.index(letter) # Index of the letter in the alphabet array where the pointer should move
    
    distance_clockwise = abs(destination - current_position)
    distance_counter = abs(len(alphabet) - destination + current_position)
                           
    distance = distance_counter if distance_clockwise > distance_counter else distance_clockwise
    
    distances.append(distance) # No of movements from current position to destination
    current_position = destination # Repositioning the pointer
    
    print(letter, distance) # Debuging...
print(sum(distances))
```

According to my test case, the string 'Croves' should have the following distances:

1. From A (pointer initial position) to C (first letter), 2 movements
2. From C to R, 11 movements
3. From R to O, 3 movements
4. From O to V, 7 movements
5. From V to E, 9 movements
6. From E to S, 12 movements
7. The total number of movements should be 44

But my code output is:

1. From A (pointer initial position) to C (first letter), 2 movements
2. From C to R, 11 movements
3. From R to O, 3 movements
4. From O to V, 7 movements
5. **From V to E, 17 movements**
6. From E to S, 12 movements
7. The total number of movements is 52

There's a bug when the pointer needs to move through the letter 'A' that I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate `distance_counter`  as `26-distance_clockwise`, which fixes the issue.

I also came up with this solution with list comprehension:

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase # String 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

word = 'Croves'.lower()

distances = {l: min(abs(alphabet.index(l) - alphabet.index(c)), 26 - abs(alphabet.index(l) - alphabet.index(c))) for l, c in zip(word, 'a' + word[:-1])}
print(distances)
    
print(sum(distances.values()))
```

Output:

```
{'r': 11, 'v': 7, 'o': 3, 'c': 2, 's': 12, 'e': 9}                                                                                                                                 
44
```

If you want the same output you can use:

```
import string
import collections

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase # String 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

word = 'Croves'.lower()

distances = collections.OrderedDict((l, (min(abs(alphabet.index(l) - alphabet.index(c)), 26 - abs(alphabet.index(l) - alphabet.index(c))))) for l, c in zip(word, 'a' + word[:-1]))

for k, v in distances.items():
    print(k, v)
    
print(sum(distances.values()))
```

Output:

```
c 2                                                                                                                                                                                
r 11                                                                                                                                                                               
o 3                                                                                                                                                                                
v 7                                                                                                                                                                                
e 9                                                                                                                                                                                
s 12                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
44
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a middle ground packing a little less into the list comprehension, and appears to have a slight run time performance advantage:

```
wheel = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def dist(c1, c2):
    d1 = abs(wheel.index(c1) - wheel.index(c2))
    return min(d1, 26 - d1)

word = 'Croves'.lower()
distances = [dist(c1, c2) for (c1, c2) in zip('a' + word, word)]
for (letter, distance) in zip(word, distances):
    print(f'{letter} {distance}')
print(sum(distances))

c 2
r 11
o 3
v 7
e 9
s 12
44
```

**Bonus option - generator function**

You can streamline the process further if you use a generator. This cuts out duplicating the `word`, and minimizes the `index` lookups.

```
def dist_gen(word):
    start = 0  # this is letter a
    for c in word:
        end = wheel.index(c)
        d = abs(end - start)
        start = end
        yield min(d, 26 - d)

word = 'Croves'.lower()
distances = list(dist_gen(word))

for (letter, distance) in zip(word, distances):
    print(f'{letter} {distance}')
print(sum(distances))

c 2
r 11
o 3
v 7
e 9
s 12
44
```